# Kafka streams error : SerializationException: Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying Kafka Streams. Writing a simple application where I am counting duplicate messages.

Message:

```
2019-02-27-11:16:56 :: session:prod-111656 :: Msg => Hello World: 2491
2019-02-27-11:16:56 :: session:prod-111656 :: Msg => Hello World: 2492
```

etc.

I am trying to split such messages by `session:prod-xxxx`. Use it as key. And `session:prod-xxxx+Hello World: xxxx` use it as value. Then group by key, and see which messages got duplicated in each session.

Here's the code:

```
KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("RegularProducer");
KTable<String, Long> ktable = textLines.map(
    (String key, String value) -> {
        try {
            String[] parts = value.split("::");
            String sessionId = parts[1];
            String message = ((parts[2]).split("=>"))[1];
            message = sessionId+":"+message;
            return new KeyValue<String,String>(sessionId.trim().toLowerCase(), message.trim().toLowerCase());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new KeyValue<String,String>("Invalid-Message".trim().toLowerCase(), "Invalid Message".trim().toLowerCase());
        }
    })
    .groupBy((key,value) -> value)
    .count().filter(
            (String key, Long value) -> {
                return value > 1;
            }
    );

ktable.toStream().to("RegularProducerDuplicates", 
Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
Topology topology = builder.build();
topology.describe();
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
streams.start();
```

KTable topic RegularProducerDuplicates gets produced. But when I use console-consumer to view it, it crashes with an error. Then I use --skip-message-on-error flag on console-consumer. Now I see thousands of lines like these

```
session:prod-111656 : hello world: 994  [2019-02-28 16:25:18,081] ERROR Error processing message, skipping this message:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8
```

Can anyone help me what's going wrong here?

Comment: you are deserializing it as if the value was a long. It seems it's not

Comment: can u pls tell me where? I am very new to streams and grappling with this style of programming.

Comment: (String key, Long value) --> seems that value is not a long (as the deserializer tells, it's not a 8 byte long value). Most surely that's a String. p.s i also don't know much about streams, but seems like a typical kafka issue

Comment: Hmmm because in previous step of count(), value being returned is type T and Long. As per the documentation. Really wondering what's wrong here.

Comment: @Shades88, Could you add to the question the whole command (kafka-console-consumer), that use for reading ?

Comment: Here it is `sh bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic RegularProducerDuplicates --from-beginning --key-deserializer org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer --value-deserializer org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer --property print.key=true --property print.value=true --skip-message-on-error`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Kafka Streams application is ok and works properly.

**The bug** is in `kafka-console-consumer` (`kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer` is class that implements logic for script).

It doesn't properly handle `null` during deserialization. When it gets `null` as value or key for a message it sets default value (Array of bytes that representing `null` String). If you check source code you can find following function

```scala
def write(deserializer: Option[Deserializer[_]], sourceBytes: Array[Byte]) {
  val nonNullBytes = Option(sourceBytes).getOrElse("null".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
  val convertedBytes = deserializer.map(_.deserialize(null, nonNullBytes).toString.
    getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).getOrElse(nonNullBytes)
  output.write(convertedBytes)
}
```

How you can see when it gets sourceBytes that is null (`sourceBytes==null`) for deserialization it set default value for that:

`val nonNullBytes = Option(sourceBytes).getOrElse("null".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`

In your case it is `"null".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. Then, there is a try of deserialization with `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer` (your value deserializer). `LongDeserializer` checks at very beginning the size of the Array of bytes. Now it is 4 (byte representation of `null`) and an exception is thrown.

If you for example use StringDeserializer, it will not deserialize it properly but at least it won't throw an exception, because it doesn't check the length of array of bytes.

**Long story short**: ConsoleConsumer's formatter, that is responsible for printing, for pretty printing set some default value, that can't be handled by some Deserializers (LongDeserializer, IntegerDeserializer)

**Regarding, why your application produce `null` values for some keys:**

The `KTable:filter` has different semantic than the `KStream::filter`. According to javadoc for KTable:

> for each record that gets dropped (i.e., does not satisfy the given
>   predicate) a tombstone record is forwarded.

For your `filter`, when `count <= 1` it passes `null` value for the key.

Comment: No it happens even if I start without --from-beginning. For every incoming line which doesn't have count = 1 or which is not duplicate, this error is thrown

Comment: @Shades88, I've update my answer with explanation what has happened.

Comment: Great explanation. In this case I want to group by, count and then filter. So I will be unable to use KStream::filter. Then how will I be able to avoid tombstone records?

Comment: Also with that filter function I am specifying Kafka Streams to give me only those records inside KTable which has value > 1. I just ran a standard Java consumer and you are right. There many records having null as value. Then what is the point of filter function?

Comment: @Shades88, When you convert `KTable` to `KStream` you can filter out tombstone recrods: `ktable.toStream.filter((key, value) -> value != null)`

Answer (score 3):

The Deserializer used for values might not be for String and will be for Long.
While creating consumer in cli do specify it. Ex-

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
    --topic name \
    --from-beginning \
    --formatter kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter \
    --property print.key=true \
    --property print.value=true \
    --skip-message-on-error \
    --property key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer \
    --property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Here check the last 2 lines while creating consumer, take care of the type of your (Key,Values) 
 In  my case both were strings, if values had been of long type, use last line as:
 **--property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that if I move the `filter` after `toStream`, the null values (tombstones) are not produced.